# Putting an object to a certain type based upon its properties

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have the following requirement.

Suppose there are 2 properties where each property can have one of 3 values (multiple choice) Hence we can have 2 x 3 = 6 different types of objects.

Given an object with these property values, I need to map it to a certain type.

What is the best way to do this in Java ? Is there any design pattern that I can consider.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a POJO that has both properties as fields, read the POJO, and infer the value that you need?  Do you have to map it to something else?

Comment: A class with 2 `enums`, each with 3 values would work..

Comment: I would create an enumeration for the different types, create a private instance of that enumeration in your object and then decide how to set this enum field appropriately

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using `enum` to implement the 2x3 options:

```
enum Types {

    TYPE1('A',1),
    TYPE2('A',2),
    TYPE3('B',1),
    TYPE4('B',2),
    TYPE5('C',1),
    TYPE6('C',2);

    private final char x;
    private final int i;

    Types(char x, int i) {
        this.x = x;
        this.i = i;
    }

}
```

In the example above, you can create each one of `Types.TYPE1,...,Types.TYPE6` by using one of the chars: `A`,`B`,`C` and one of the ints: `1`,`2`.

Of course that this is only an example and you can replace `char` and `int` with any other property you need.

Comment: and How to use it from external class ?

Comment: @NinadPingale post it as a separate question with a concrete example, and I'll show you how.

Comment: @NinadPingale do you mean like `Types.TYPE1` or `Types.TYPE6` as it suggests in the answer?

Comment: @PeterLawrey : I meant how to call `Types(char x, int i)` - like `new Type('A',5)` or some other way ?

Comment: @NinadPingale nope, you can either call `Types.Type1` or implement another method in the enum: `Types getType(char x, int i)`